# Click to expand, collapse all others when clicked

Tags: jquery

I've had a lot of success with the following jquery function. It allows you to hide content until the title is clicked, then it expands the ul item.  I love this feature, however I'd really like only one ul to be open at a time. How can I make it so that when a title is clicked, it expands that one, and collapses all the rest that are open?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Slide
            $('#expandable_menu > ul > a.expanded + li').slideToggle('slow');
            $('#expandable_menu > ul > a').click(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass('expanded').toggleClass('collapsed').parent().find('> li').slideToggle('slow');
            });

        }, 250);
    });  
</script>
```

Here's the structure of the stuff that expands and collapses.

```
<ul id="expandable_menu" class="expandable_menu">

     <ul>
         <a class="expanded">TITLE</a>
     <li class="expandablemenu" ">
          <ul>
                   <li>
                        <div> This is where the content goes </div>
                    </li>
          </ul>
     </li>
      </ul>

     <ul>
         <a class="expanded">TITLE</a>
     <li class="expandablemenu" ">
          <ul>
                   <li>
                        <div> More content! </div>
                    </li>
          </ul>
     </li>
      </ul>

</ul>
```

Comment: can you post the relevant html so I can make a fiddle? EDIT: Or, better yet, you make a fiddle and post it here...

Comment: `ul > a` ? anchor cannot be a direct descendant of ul....

Comment: Hi brbcoding, I posted the html for you on the original question.  Thanks!

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eYQSJ/
This works for the original code, the problem is getting the others to collapse when a new title is clicked.
@brbcoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw that you updated with a fiddle... I don't have much time, but you could just hide everything first if you wanted to, and then go ahead and toggle the one you actually want to toggle.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Slide
        $('#expandable_menu > ul > a.collapsed + li').slideToggle('slow');
        $('#expandable_menu > ul > a').click(function () {
            // I only added this
            $('#expandable_menu > ul > li').hide('slow');
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded').toggleClass('collapsed').parent().find('> li').slideToggle('slow');
        });

    }, 250);
});
```

**[Forked & Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eYQSJ/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to use jqueryUi for this,there is an accordion control thats exactly for the scenario you have described. Accordion control has various options related to its behaviour. You can take a look at accordion at jqueryUi site. Its very easy to implement. Another thing.. If you donot want to use another lib... It can easily be done using js also. Paste your html here,that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the first statement. I'm assuming the li is the next element to the title.
So instead of doing a slideToggle on all of the li's you want to be more specific as to which ones to slideUp and slideDown.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Slide
            $('#expandable_menu > ul > a.expanded + li').slideToggle('slow');
        }, 250);
        $('#expandable_menu > ul > a').click(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass("expanded"){
                $(this).next("li").slideUp();
            }
            else{
                $(this).next('li').slideDown() //opening the next li which is the title you wanted
                    .siblings('li').slideUp(); //find all the other li's and slide up
            }
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded').toggleClass('collapsed');
        });
    });  
</script>
```

Added code for the element to slide back up as you have requested. Basically you need to check if the link has the class, if it does then slideUp because it is already open, otherwise slideDown because it wasn't opened.

Comment: I think it's close, but the items won't slide back up.  I'll post the structure in the original question.

Comment: @user2755541 updated my answer so the item will slide back up as well.